# Firefox: limit file upload dialog to mp3 only

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I am using jquery file upload to upload files to a server. I want to only allow the user to be able to select mp3 files. Within Safari and Chrome it works fine if I add an accept attribute in the following way:

```
<input accept="audio/mpeg" type="file" name="file" />
```

However, this does not work with firefox. I have tried the following mime types, but nothing works. All file types are still selectable.

```
audio/mp3
audio/mpeg
audio/mpeg3
audio/x-mpeg-3
video/mpeg
video/x-mpeg
```

However, I noticed that if I use

```
audio/*
```

I am only able to select audio files with Firefox. What would be a mime type for mp3 that firefox would recognise?

**Edit:**

Interestingly the mime type submitted with the uploaded file by firefox is `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: have you tried `video/*` ?

Comment: can do... now I can't even select audio files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible with Firefox, at least for the time being (v27.0.1). A bug has been filed [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176), but nothing substantial has happened since.

On account of the MP3 MIME type, 'audio/mpeg' is indeed the MIME type for mp3 files. But for posterity, [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/sound_mime_type.htm) is a list of that and other audio MIME types from webdesign.about.com.